# How will i bind Web Grid in MVC 3 from DataSet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

@{
     var grid = new WebGrid(source: ViewBag.AllUsers,//in view Bag we have dataset to bind 
                         rowsPerPage: 10);

```
    }
    @grid.GetHtml(
                 tableStyle: "gridtable",
        alternatingRowStyle: "even",

    columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("UserId", "Id"),
                    grid.Column("userName", "Name"),
                    grid.Column("City", "City"),
                    grid.Column("Designation","Designation"),
                    grid.Column("sal","Salary")
                   )            


                )
            )
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller put the code like this

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult View(Modelclass viewmodel)
    {
        List<Modelclass> employees = new List<Modelclass>();
        DataSet ds = viewmodel.GetAllAuthors();
        var empList = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => new Modelclass{
           AuthorId = dataRow.Field<int>("AuthorId"),
            Fname = dataRow.Field<string>("FName"),
           Lname = dataRow.Field<string>("Lname")
        });
        var list = empList.ToList();



        return View(list);
    }
```

And in view

```
@gd.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table",

            columns: gd.Columns(
                     gd.Column("AuthorId", "AuthorId"),
                     gd.Column("Fname", " Fname"),
                     gd.Column("Lname", "Lname", style: "description")

     ))
```